# how to restrict html tags in query string in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

how to handle request when user directly enters html content in URL. 
I want to redirect to Error page when user enters html tag in URL is that possible in MVC.

I have tried from `BeginExecute` event of by creating override method.

Please give some suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Any sample code available to reproduce? Can you provide examples of forbidden query string URLs that you want to block using described event?

Comment: No I want to block any query that contains html in query string value

Comment: @KevinShah did you try to use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(), you can get query string params and check them to understand whether they have html tag or not

Comment: If user enters any html tag in querystring it will not go to action as because in my action I haven't set AllowHtml attribute

Answer (score 1):

> meybe can use `RouteHandler` for when a user needs to redirect to any
>   external page, shorten long URLs, or make URLs more user friendly.

please check my answer

[Error handling ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288309/error-handling-asp-net-mvc/46288620#46288620)

Answer (score 1):

You can always choose `CustomErrorMode="On"` in web.config and configure with your error controller

`Custom Error Mode` will help you to redirect any invalid or malicious link or content to redirect it to your errorcontroller and handle it the way you want.

Comment: this will redirect to Error page that is correct but I do not want to redirect user on error page but dispaly message but now its ok with redirection

Comment: Anyways with redirection you can display a message if any html content is entered in URL and you can configure it in your route by specifying the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Request validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx) for do it. It prevents to accept un-encoded HTML/XML etc from Client to server. It validates all the data that is passed from client to server. To use this feature , you must set `requestValidationMode` as **4.5** in `web.config` like:

```
<httpruntime requestvalidationmode="4.5" />
```

For more information please see [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/358993/Examining-Request-Validation-with-ASP-NET).